# how to validate no duplicated int type data in java

Tags: java

I wanted to check whether the txt file contain duplicate data or not when i click the button load Data.

For example ID, ID in an int.
0001
0002
0003

here is the partial code

```
while (scnr.hasNextInt()) 
{
   id  = scnr.nextInt();

   int checkid = id;
   if(checkid == id) {
        System.out.println("invalid id");
   } else{
        clients.put(new Integer(id), new Client(id));
   }
}
```

This code doesn't work.
And also, i had tried this method but it is not working too.

```
    if(checkid.matches(id))
    {
        System.out.println("invalid id");
    }
```

> Cannot invoke matches (int) on the primitive type int

i not understand why String type data can use .matches() but int cannot.
what method i can implant to validate the int type data????

Comment: convert it to a string, then: `checkid.matches("" + id)`

Comment: Don't call `new Integer(id)`. It will happen automatically, which is called [*autoboxing*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that should work for you. Use a HashSet to store ids and check if the Set contains the id.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class SetExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    Set<Integer> ids = new HashSet<>();
    int id;

    while (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
        id = scnr.nextInt();

        if (ids.contains(id)) {
            System.out.println("invalid id");
        } else {
            ids.add(id);
            clients.put(new Integer(id), new Client(id));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can u briefly exaplain for me why ids.add(id) is needed?
what it gonna to add?

Comment: ids is the collection that stores the entered ids so you can check if new ids are already contained, adding to it is how ids get added to the collection.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should understand `int` is not a class but a [primitive type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) in Java, you can't invoke a method on it.

Second, you want to find duplicate elements, so you should try [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Last, if you are new to programming language, you can try *Head First Java*; otherwise, you may want to have a look at *Thinking In Java*

Answer (score -1):

The reason why your code doesn't work is quite obvious: You set `checkid` to `id` and then check if they are equal. If you want to check every new id against previous ids, you need to keep track of the ids that were already read, e. g. using a `List` or a `Set`as mentioned before.

Something along theese lines would do:

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
while (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
    id = scnr.nextInt();
    if (ids.contains(id)) {
       System.out.println("invalid id");
    } else {
        ids.add(id);
        clients.put(new Integer(id), new Client(id));
    }
}
```

> i not understand why String type data can use .matches() but int cannot.

`String` is a [complex datatype](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jsoap_5/index1.html), `int` is a [primitive datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) that does not support methods. Anyhow, `.matches()` wouldn't do the job because it compares against a [regular expression](http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/). `.equals` would be a better choice, but again, not for `int`.

Comment: Why not `List.contains`?

Comment: `ArrayList.contains()` is *O(n)* performance, while `HashSet.contains()` is *O(1)*. Total for the loop is *O(n²)* for `List` vs. *O(n)* for `Set`. Humongous difference if number of values is large.